# k-Nearest-Neighbor for Factorial Based Data

Tags: regression, k-nearest-neighbour

This week I read about using the kNN algorithm to predict the outcome of a continuous variable based on the input of one or more continuous variables. The example was predicting the price of a wine bottle based on rating and age.

Is it possible for this to be used to predict a continuous outcome based on factorial based data? For example, predicting the cost of a car based on manufacturer, model, warranty, etc? Or perhaps predicting the attendance of a basketball game based on opponent, day of week, time of day, etc?

In similar situations in the past I have converted each factor to a number, but I'm curious to know if there's a way to skip that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of KNN is to use the known labels of data points to predict that of a closeby data point for which you do not have a label. So, you can apply KNN to a dataset as long as there is a measure of distance between objects.

The challenge in your case would be what distance measure to define between two objects (cars). Ask yourself, when would I consider two cars to be similar? Are there manufacturers that are more similar to one another? Of course you can always trivially use a measure in which the distance is 0 if the factor is similar or large otherwise.

Another question is then if you have different types of distance measures for different types, how to combine them. You can always standardize each feature and then use something like euclidean distance, but there a lot of other ways to go, specifically you could give different weights to different features and use that to scale them differently.

The last point is that you have a lot of different options here - you can evaluate everything with appropriate cross-validations and pick the best.

Comment: Thanks for informative answer. I understand your point about finding a measurable distance between two points. I'm not sure that I understand differing types of measurements for different types of data points. I do understand having different weights for various sets of data points, but somehow I thought euclidean distance was the only type of measurement in kNN. Can you give an example of another type, and maybe when it would be warranted? Thanks again, this is helpful.

Comment: @Lenwood http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html provides some common distance metrics. Each one has different properties so it is impossible to discuss all of them, but one example is Hamming distance which is usually used for string comparison. Another example is Pearson correlation distance which differs from Euclidean distance in that each vector is normalized, so [1,2,3,4] would be close to [10,20,30,40] in correlation distance but far in Euclidean distance.

Comment: Once again, thanks for informative answer. That link is a great resource and your example makes sense as well. Over the next few days I'll look at a few of these measurements with my data, to see which makes the most sense.